# How to update data in database with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

When I update the data in the database using the form below, the error following error is shown.  How can I solve this error?

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`nov-cms`.`faqs_cat`, CONSTRAINT `faqs_cat_ibfk_20` FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
REFERENCES `tblfaqs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)'
```

Form:

```
    function editpage_($editid) {
        $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
        $data['headingtop'] = "FAQ'S > FAQ'S > Edit FAQ'S";
        $data['title_faqs'] = "Edit FAQ's";




        $data['errormess'] = '';
        $title_faqs = addslashes($this->input->post('title_faqs'));
        $content = addslashes($this->input->post('editor1'));
        $seo_description = addslashes($this->input->post('seo_description'));
        $category = $this->input->post('category'); //print_r($category['cate']);   exit;
        $isActive = $this->input->post('isactive');
        $position = $this->input->post('position');
$qryDel2 = $conn->prepare("DELETE from faqs_cat where id='$editid'");
   $qryDel2->execute();


 $query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE  tblfaqs SET title_faqs='$title_faqs',content='$content',isActive='$isActive',position='$position',seo_description='$seo_description' WHERE id='$editid' ");
        $query->execute();
        $id = $conn->lastInsertId();
        //when we add a page this insert a record to table, and this is id of record inserted.. this is a function default of mysql, we use to get last insert id to insert this to orther table...
        foreach ($category as $data) {
            $query = $conn->prepare("insert into faqs_cat (fc_id, id, category_id) values ('','$id','$data')"); //in this.
            $query->execute();
        }
 $url = 'admin/faqs/';
        echo'   
<script>
window.location.href = "' . base_url() . $url . '";
</script>
';
```

Comment: I see code and an error, but no question.

Comment: Question updated @celeo

Comment: the error is quite clear: youre trying to modify a row changing a foreing key and the new foreign key doesnt exist in the parent table

Comment: as you seen in the code first i deleted the row having same id and then i update the data into the two tables. Forign key exist in the parent table

Comment: Is this CodeIgniter? Why aren't you using models?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line:

```
$id = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

Specifically, `$id` remains empty because `lastInsertId()` is not returning a value. This causes the constraint to fail because when inserting into `faqs_cat` an ID is required.

If you're trying to get an auto-generated key from the database, you may need to specify a sequence name to `lastInsertId` depending on what type of database you're connecting to (for example, Postgres requires a sequence name). Try creating a sequence called 'mySequence' and using this instead:

```
$id = $conn->lastInsertId('mySequence');
```